# Convert int to list in python

Tags: python

Take a list, say for example this one:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

and write a program that prints out all the elements of the list as the list [1,1,2,3,5] that are less than 5.
Currently it prints as

```
1
1
2
3
5
```

My code

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
count = 0
for i in a:
    if i<=5:
        count+=1
        print(i)
```

Comment: Am I missing something? It looks like the expected and actual output match.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey he needs it formated like [...] not just spaced

Comment: Are you just asking how to format the output so it looks like `[1,1,2,3,5]` instead of `1 1 2 3 5`? If so, it's probably advisable to drop the part of the question that just recaps the homework problem you were on when this came up. It's confusing as currently presented.

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thanks all.

Comment: You state *all the elements of the list as the list that are less than 5* but your example `[1,1,2,3,5]` is less than or equal to 5...

Comment: You can do `filter(lambda e: e<=5, a)`

Answer (score 1):

To have it print out as a list, keep it as a list.  You can use list comprehension to accomplish this:

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
>>> [i for i in a if i<=5]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

If we use `print`, it still looks the same:

```
>>> print([i for i in a if i<=5])
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Could you also use `filter`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, very true.  In py2, one could use `filter(lambda x: x<=5, a)` or, in either py2 or py3, one could use `list(filter(lambda x: x<=5, a))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all to print out all the element that great and **equal to** 5 then you are doing it right. But if you want to print out less then 5 you want:

```
for i in a:
    if i < 5:
        count += 1
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the if condition be more strict if you want only element smaller than 5. It should be `if i<5:` instead of `i<=5`.

If you want to store the elements in a new list, see the example below.

```
a = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
new_list=[]
for i in a:
    if i<5:
        new_list.append(i)
print new_list
```